# Using the django package graphos, how can I change the color of the individual bars of the graph?

Tags: django, web, web-frameworks

I'm able to get the example running, but I just want to get comfortable with customizing graphs. How can I change the color of the bars?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am still new to django and javascript, these links might help you.

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-to-change-the-bar-color-in-a-google-column-chart

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. Include the essential parts of the link to your answer instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Wtower, new to StackOverflow will keep this in mind going forward.